# php syntax error: unexpected '/', while using use or namespace statement

Tags: php, syntax, namespaces, syntax-error

I'm using a php code right from [bigbluebutton php API](https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton-api-php/wiki/Environment-Variables) documentation, but it doesnt work.
Here is the code:

```
use BigBlueButton/BigBlueButton;

$bbb                 = new BigBlueButton();
$createMeetingParams = new CreateMeetingParameters('bbb-meeting-uid-65', 'BigBlueButton API Meeting');
$response            = $bbb->createMeeting($createMeetingParams);

echo "Created Meeting with ID: " . $response->getMeetingId();
```

I get this error from php logs:

> syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting ',' or ';' in
> /var/www/html/bbbapi/index.php on line 1

I'm running it using php 5.6 on ubuntu 16.4 i've tried a slash and a backslash but it just wont work i'm very surprised by this, since i've used  `use`  by the past.
Anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change `'/'` by `'\'` in your code:

```
use BigBlueButton\BigBlueButton;
```

**UPDATE:**

I tested in a simple php file and added this changes to make work:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use BigBlueButton\BigBlueButton;
use BigBlueButton\Parameters\CreateMeetingParameters;

$bbb                 = new BigBlueButton();
$createMeetingParams = new CreateMeetingParameters('bbb-meeting-uid-65', 'BigBlueButton API Meeting');
$response            = $bbb->createMeeting($createMeetingParams);

echo "Created Meeting with ID: " . $response->getMeetingId();
```

Comment: As said in my post i've already tried this, and it doesnt work

Comment: i get this error:  Class 'BigBlueButton\BigBlueButton' not found in /var/www/html/bbbapi/index.php on line 5

Comment: I updated the answer. I don't know where you are trying to use this, but i tested in here in a simple php file and added this changes.

Comment: Thanks that solved the issue; i also had to add `use BigBlueButton\Parameters\CreateMeetingParameters;`